# improve the resolution of saved eps file

Tags: matlab

I generate a dendrogram plot with a lot of leaf node. It become quite difficult to read the node label on the saved eps file. Is there a way to setup the page size  during the saving process? Thus the resolution of the plot can be increased and the these labels can be readable.

Comment: An eps file should not have a distinct "resolution" like pixel images (except that you're storing a bitmap-like structure inside an eps file, which is possible, but most of the time not really useful). You can zoom in like you want without loss of quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the File menu of the figure, then Export setup. You can set page size and resolution here, but I would try to play with "Scale font by" first (press Apply to figure to see the effect).